# load value from property file in @entity

Tags: java, entity

I have a class

```
@Entity
class foo {

  private string name = ;

}
```

I want to initialize the above varaible foo.name using a value read from a file foo.properties without using resourceBundle.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the official [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) you can create a Property object the following way:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("my.properties");
properties.load(in);
in.close();
```

Then you can access a value using [getProperty(String key)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29) like:

```
String name = properties.getProperty("keyName");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have on your constructor something like:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream("/tmp/properties.txt"));
this.name = props.getProperty("propertyName");
```